# Why is giving this error? " int('A'[1]) IndexError: string index out of range"

Tags: python, string, numbers, converters, sequences

```
#this script will go to strip strings and replace for numbers A=1 T=2 C=3 G=4

input='fastas_joined'
output='saida_joined'

from Bio import SeqIO

input2=open(input, 'r')
output2=open(output, 'a')

for a in SeqIO.parse(input2, 'fasta'):
        a_seq=a.seq
        for b in a_seq:
                int('A'[1])
        #.convert('a', 1)
        #str.convert('T', 2)
        #str.convert('t', 2)
        #a_seq.str.convert('C', 3)
        #a_seq.str.convert('c', 3)
        #a_seq.str.convert('G', 4)
        #a_seq.str.convert('g', 4)
        #print a_seq.int.convert('A', 1)
        #for b in a.seq:
        #       if 'A' convert('A', 1)
```

Comment: you mean this `int(A[1])` ?

Comment: What are you trying to get by doing `int('A'[1])`? Who is `A`?

Answer (score 1):

The incriminated line is:

```
int('A'[1])
```

The part in the brackets is asking for the second character (index 1) of the string "A", that has only one character.

Very likely not what you intended to do.